# How can I trigger video via remote?

Tags: video, remote, tethering, nikon-d750

I recently began using a Zhiyun crane with my Nikon D750 and I am trying to find out if it is possible to focus the camera and/or trigger the video on the camera by means of a remote control.

As it is, reaching for the focus while managing the crane is an exercise in dexterity, so if there is a way to focus and start/stop the video using a remote that would be really handy.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general term for what you're trying to do is called **[tethering](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering)**. The D750 supports tethering quite well. You can remotely set exposure settings, engage autofocus, trigger the shutter and/or start video recording, as well as preview and transfer images.

Note that video production usually relies on manual (perhaps motorized) focus control, via a focus puller. There are several options on the market for motorized focus control, and for adding follow-focus gearing to photographic lenses. *Note: These options are beyond the scope of this site, but are on-topic at the [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://avp.stackexchange.com).*

Some tethering connections can be made wireless, some are strictly wired. As a starting point, I suggest the following:

- [Using Your Nikon Camera's Built-in Wi-Fi](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/learn-and-explore/a/tips-and-techniques/using-your-nikon-cameras-built-in-wi-fi.html) at Nikon USA
- [Tethering options for the D750](https://www.tethertools.com/camera/nikon-d750/) at tethertools.com
- [Nikon D750 Supported Features](http://camranger.com/nikon-d750/) at camranger.com (CamRanger is a wireless tethering accessory)